# ¿Cómo se pueden implementar URLs diferentes con misma funcionalidad sin repetir código?

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-boot, diseño

Tengo una duda sobre el diseño de una Api REST. Tengo un escenario como sigue:

- El recurso `/clientes/{id}/inmuebles` me devuelve los inmuebles que le pertenecen a este cliente identificado por su id.
- El recurso `/inmuebles?idcliente={idCliente}` me devuelve el mismo resultado descrito anteriormente.

Mi problema está en el diseño de controladores para estas dos rutas, puesto que con una implementación sencilla termino con código repetido. Tengo un código como sigue (muy simplificado, con el fin de expresar mi problema):

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/clientes")
public class ClienteController {
    @Autowired
    private InmuebleService inmuebleService;

    @RequestMapping(path="/{id}/inmuebles", method=GET)
    public Page<Inmueble> getInmueblesUsuario(
        @PathVariable Long id,
        @RequestParam(required=false, defaultValue="0") int offset,
        @RequestParam(required=false, defaultValue="20") int limit) {
        //se va a repetir luego
        return inmuebleService.getInmueblesUsuario(idCliente, offset, limit);
    }
}

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/inmuebles")
public class InmuebleController {
    @Autowired
    private InmuebleService inmuebleService;

    @RequestMapping(method=GET)
    public Page<Inmueble> getInmuebles(
        @RequestParam(required=false) Long idCliente,
        @RequestParam(required=false, defaultValue="0") int offset,
        @RequestParam(required=false, defaultValue="20") int limit) {
        //código repetido
        //inclusive las variables del método se repiten
        return inmuebleService.getInmueblesUsuario(idCliente, offset, limit);
    }
}
```

¿Bajo el modelo de usar `@RequestMapping` para cada controlador, existe alguna manera de evitar repetir el código? ¿Existe alguna manera más ordenada de diseñar la implementación de estos 2 servicios que siga tanto [DRY](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/No_te_repitas) (no te repitas) como [KISS](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principio_KISS) (mantenlo simple)?

P.D.: Los enlaces de wikipedia de DRY y KISS en inglés brindan más información.

Answer (score 0):

`@RequestMapping` recibe como `value` un `String[]`, con lo que podrías usar una misma clase para mapear varias URLs.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value={"/clientes","/inmuebles"})
```

Ahora podrías añadir en la misma clase los dos métodos, ya que los `paths` son diferentes entre ellos y `Spring` no tendría problemas al resolver cuál es el indicado.

Te quedaría algo así:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value={"/clientes","/inmuebles"})
public class SuperController {
    @Autowired
    private InmuebleService inmuebleService;

    @RequestMapping(path="/{id}/inmuebles", method=GET)
    public Page<Inmueble> getInmueblesUsuario(
        @PathVariable Long id,
        @RequestParam(required=false, defaultValue="0") int offset,
        @RequestParam(required=false, defaultValue="20") int limit) {
        //se va a repetir luego
        return inmuebleService.getInmueblesUsuario(idCliente, offset, limit);
    }

    @RequestMapping(method=GET)
    public Page<Inmueble> getInmuebles(
        @RequestParam(required=false) Long idCliente,
        @RequestParam(required=false, defaultValue="0") int offset,
        @RequestParam(required=false, defaultValue="20") int limit) {
        //código repetido
        //inclusive las variables del método se repiten
        return getInmueblesUsuario(idCliente, offset, limit);
    }
}
```

Si hay más métodos no comunes es obvio que esta solución no sería apropiada, pero en ese caso no veo por qué habría necesidad de refactorizar más el código que presentas.

Por un lado la llamada a la lógica de negocio común ya está en un único lugar, `InmueblesService`.

Por otro tienes separada la lógica asociada a cada tipo de recurso, clientes e inmuebles.

No veo por qué querrías, o sería necesario, hacer cambios.

Comment: Son controladores distintos. Hay más métodos en cada controlador (omitido por simplicidad del caso). Además, en la parte final de la pregunta indico que debo usar `@RequetMapping` a nivel de controlador.

Comment: bajo mi desconocimiento del lenguaje... no seria mas correcto hacer un metodo privado que procesara el dato, y que los metodos de controlador de url devolveran el resultado de ese metodo?

Comment: @Jakala son dos controladores distintos, por ende dos clases distintas... No pueden compartir un método privado entre ambas...

Comment: No lo entiendo. El ejemplo de código de @pablo muestra una clase controlador con varios métodos get... No están en clases distintas tampoco,  por lo que parecería correcto lo de un método privado que compartan ambas acciones... Hay algo en Java que lo prohiba?

Answer (score 0):

Si lo que te refieres es a que se repite la definición del controller, del método y requestmaping y de las variables de entrada **no lo veo mal**.

Ese código esta repetido, pero es un código repetido bueno. Es decir que aunque visualmente sean iguales, sintacticamente tienen significados distintos: Estás definiendo distintos puntos de entrada para tu aplicación bien diferencias. Pienso sinceramente que lo has hecho bien, has concentrado tu caso de uso en un servicio y lo has expuesto al exterior de dos formas distintas. El principio DRY (no te repitas) muchas veces se mal interpreta.

---

Dicho esto, si sigues queriendo eliminar este código (cosa que me parece un error) puedes hacer un rewrite de la request de entrada mediante [la definición de un filtro personalizado](http://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-custom-filter). En el podrías [redirigir las llamadas de una url a otra teniendo finalmente un único controlador](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2725102/how-to-use-a-servlet-filter-in-java-to-change-an-incoming-servlet-request-url).

```
public class CustomFilter extends GenericFilterBean {

    @Override
    public void doFilter( ServletRequest request, 
                          ServletResponse response,
                          FilterChain chain)
                          throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest = ((HttpServletRequest) request);
        String requestURI = httpServletRequest.getRequestURI();

    if (isRewritableUri(requestURI)) {
        String newUrl= toNewUrl(requestURI);
        RequestDispatcher dispatcher = wrapper.getRequestDispatcher(newUrl);
        dispatcher.forward(req, res);
    } else {
        chain.doFilter(httpServletRequest, response);
    }


        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
}
```

Solo tendrías que implementar el metodo isRewritableUri que te indicaría si es una url que debes redirigir y toNewUrl que transformaría una url en la otra.

Como puedes ver creo que esto es un trabajo de sobre-ingeniería que complicaría tu aplicación y ocultaría detalles, haciendola menos mantenible en vez de al contrario.